# Is there a buffer when one uses the 'readline()' method? Can i access previously 'read/accessed' lines of txt?

Tags: python, file, readline

Suppose I had opened to read a text file under name `fileOpened`, and it has the following lines:
line1
line2
line3
line4

If I execute `fileOpened.readline()` once, the output will be: `'line1'`.
If I execute `fileOpened.readline()` again, the output will be: `'line2'`.

My question is:

Is there a method which would allow me to access the previous/last line I 'produced' from the `readline()` function from some other function, say arbitrary function `lastline()` (`readline()` position - one line) on `fileOpened.lastline()` would output me: `'line2'`?

Comment: "s there a method which would allow me..." The technique is to remember the information yourself, by assigning it to a variable. It's possible to jump around in files, but this generally works on the *byte* level, and generally you'll still have to *remember* a position to jump back to, if you want to jump back to a previous position. All of this is caused by *how files work*, not by Python.

Comment: Python does (indirectly) buffer some file contents in memory while reading, for efficiency reasons; but you don't get direct access to that buffer, and it would never be guaranteed to contain (all of) the "previous line" anyway, plus there wouldn't be any direct way to figure out where that line started.